# How to put data currently in a const object within the script in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a program that takes in parameters from a form and uses them to generate a narrative comment (meant for teachers that need to write narrative comments on grade reports):

```
const sentences = {
    "participation": "engages productively in class discussions",
    "assignments": "completes all assignments on time",
    "mastery": "shows excellent understanding of the content on all assessments"
}

function writeComment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let schoolClass = document.getElementById('schoolClass').value;
    let term = document.getElementById('term').value;
    let strength1 = sentences[document.getElementById('strength1').value];
    let strength2 = sentences[document.getElementById('strength2').value];
    let result = `It has been wonderful having ${name} in ${schoolClass} during the ${term} term!
                    ${name} ${strength1}. ${name} ${strength2}`

    document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
}
```

I'd like to store const sentences in a separate file, with other similar objects, that the current script would read from and use to populate the result. Is there a way to do that? I've tried storing it in a json file and using fetch on a local server but I wasn't able to actually make the data accessible to the script.

Comment: Fetching a json file should work. As should just moving that global variable into a separate script and executing both of them together. It all hinges on the question: where and how do you include this script, how do you "run the program"?

Comment: I want the script and the variable to be separate because the variable is going to soon be MUCH bigger, with many more key-value pairs. How could I fetch the JSON in such a way that the data from the json file populates to an object that this script can use?

Comment: Load it, parse it, use it? Please show us the code that you tried and that didn't work, and what errors you got, otherwise we can't tell what went wrong.

Comment: I know how to do this: `fetch('sentences.json').then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));` but this just shows the data in the console instead of making it available to the script. I don't know how to load the data so that the script can use it.

Comment: Well, just put the entire script (at least the parts that should use the data) in that callback in place of the `console.log(data)`. Or do you mean a global variable by "*making it available*"?

Comment: That worked! I did this: `fetch('sentences.json').then(response => response.json()).then(data => composeComment(data));` Then I put the code from above into the composeComment function. Thanks so much for your help! If you want to put your suggestion in an answer so I can mark it as correct I'm happy to do that and boost your Stack cred :)